Having issues with formatting a script for job submission on LSF
Please help me as I am relatively new to using the bash shell. I have a simple script that I want to submit as a job on the LSF my institution's computing cluster uses using the bsub command like this:
bsub \
  -R rusage[mem=8G] \
  -R span[hosts=1] \
  -n 1 \
  -q short \
  -W 2:00 \
  -o log.N1.kallisto_calc.out \
  -e log.N1.kallisto_calc.err \
  -J kallisto_calc_test \
  kallisto_stats=$(zcat N1_pear_merged.fastq.gz | \
    awk '
      BEGIN {t=0.0; sq=0.0; n=0;};
      NR%4==2 {n++; L=length($0); t+=L; sq+=L*L;}
      END {m=t/n; printf("total %d avg_length %f std_dev %f\n",n,m,sqrt(sq/n-m*m));}
    '
  ) && echo -e N10'\t'$kallisto_stats >> kallisto_stats2.txt

However, when I do this, the script does not run. When I check the status using bjobs, it says "RUN" under the status but it doesn't finish and doesn't even make log files.
When I run it in this format it runs with no problems:
#BSUB -R rusage[mem=8G]
#BSUB -R span[hosts=1]
#BSUB -n 1
#BSUB -q short
#BSUB -W 2:00
#BSUB -o log.N1.kallisto_calc.out
#BSUB -e log.N1.kallisto_calc.err
#BSUB -J kallisto_calc_test

kallisto_stats=$(zcat N1_pear_merged.fastq.gz | awk 'BEGIN {t=0.0; sq=0.0; n=0;}; NR%4==2 {n++; L=length($0); t+=L; sq+=L*L;} END {m=t/n; printf("total %d avg_length %f std_dev %f\n",n,m,sqrt(sq/n-m*m));}') && echo -e N10'\t'$kallisto_stats >> kallisto_stats2.txt

This has never happened to me before, can anyone tell me what is going wrong here? If it helps, the cluster runs Linux Red Hat 8.
I tried putting the command in quotes and it did not help. The script should read the "N1_pear_merged.fastq.gz " file and make a new file called "kallisto_stats.txt" with a line of text like this:
total 100 avg_length 223.410000 std_dev 47.398121

In the first form, the command substitution -- the $( ) operation --  is invoked in your outer shell before bsub is ever started, it's not distributed as a job for remote nodes to run. Similarly, the echo runs after bsub completes, on your local client system, not on the worker nodes.

@CharlesDuffy thanks for the reply! How can I differentiate the bsub command from the script itself? I tried wrapping the commands in double quotes and it doesn't help.

I'd need to know more about bsub's usage, but if it just runs arbitrary commands exactly as it receives them, consider embedding the code you want to distribute in a function. If you define a function with yourfunc() { ...; }, for example -- putting your actual code in place of ... -- then you can run bsub ... bash -c "$(declare -f yourfunc); yourfunc", with all your other arguments in place of the second ....

As a separate aside -- any time you use square brackets in an argument, it's safer to quote it. That is to say, -R 'rusage[mem=8G]' is safer than -R rusage[mem=8G], since the latter can be parsed as a glob, which would make its behavior depend on filesystem content in the current directory (for example, if you ran that command in a directory containing a file named rusagem or rusagee, the shell could replace the word with either or both of those names).
